# How to change code highlight in jekyll-now to Monokai theme

Tags: css, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I want to change the syntax highlighting of **jekyll-now** to **monokai** like theme.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out ;)

Changing the **_highlights.scss** file would help.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Bhupesh-V/a8bc3874ccaed7b1cf3661f2448b99d0) is sample implementation of Monokai Theme